# accessing server reply using php with the help of javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a web app where user could change the layout of this web app using html , css.  For that I have created a class ,

```
<?php
class style_class_registration
{


function user_name($arr)
{

    return '<input class="user_reg_front_custom_temp ' . $arr['add_class'] . '" id="uname" size="40" type="text" name="uname"/>';
}


function  email($arr)
{
    return '<input class="user_reg_front_custom_temp ' . $arr['add_class'] . '" id="uemail" size="40" id="email" type="text" name="uemail"/>';
}

function  password($arr)
{
    return '<input class="user_reg_front_custom_temp ' . $arr['add_class'] . '" id="upass" size="40" type="password" name="upass"/>';
}

function  conf_pass($arr)
{
    return '<input class="user_reg_front_custom_temp ' . $arr['add_class'] . '" id="upass_conf" size="40" type="password" name="upass_conf""/>';

}
}
function ........
   ...................
 .................. 
    ?>
```

And theme developer of that web app could develop a theme by using those methods with html,css like this

```
<?php


$init=new style_class_registration;
echo $init->submit_button($arr_submit);


echo "<table> <tr><td>";
echo $init->user_name($arr);
echo "</td></tr> <tr> <td>";

echo $init->email($arr);

echo "</td></tr>  <tr><td>";

echo $init->password($arr);
echo "</td></tr> <tr></td>";

 echo $init->conf_pass($arr);
echo "</td></tr> <tr><td>";


echo $init->get_class($arr);
echo "</td></tr> </table>";
echo $init->display_confirmation_data(array("overflow" => "false"));


?>
```

Everything working perfectly without " `display_confirmation_data()` " method . When data is sent , theme developer could display the server reply as they want  using method "`display_confirmation_data()` ".

For sending data to server I used ajax using jquery ( theme developer dont need to make any change here, its a core area ) after pressing send button , which will be created by calling method " `echo $init->submit_button($arr_submit);` "

I have a jquery code something like this

```
   jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data_student_reg,
            url: 'process.php',
            success: get_output
        });
```

"`get_output`" javascript function receives the server reply .

But I want to access the server reply using a php method like this,

```
$init->display_confirmation_data();
```

### UPDATE

To say shortly , if I call this method " `$init->submit_button($arr_submit);`" it displays a submit button to browser . Similarly I need to print the server reply using a method (when the submit button is clicked ) , in my case "`display_confirmation_data()`" method after sending the form to server (currently I can get server reply using "get_output" function , but its a javascript function) .

**Note**: My whole codes/ methods is returning some html elements (for a registration form , I have created a class so that any theme developer can design the form as they want ) , I am trying to write a method for returning the error or success message from server (here is my problem , I can receive the server reply with a javascript function . But I need to access it with php  ) 
. ITS A LITTLE PART OF MY PROJECT , I HAVE OTHER TASKS TOO .

Is it possible ? is there any other way ?

Comment: sorry my friend but your question is unclear, what exactly do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: I have updated my post.

My whole codes/ methods is returning some html elements (for a registration form , I have created a class so that any theme developer can design the form as they want ) , I am trying to write a method for returning the error or success message from server (here is my problem , I can receive the server reply with a javascript funtion . But I need to access it with php  )

Comment: hmmmm , why do you want to access it with php ? if you want to change only a portion of the page then that's what ajax is for, isn't ajax sufficient to you ?

Comment: actually I dont want to let the theme designer to edit the core files ( where contains that ajax code and a javascript function which receives the server reply )  . If you think about " WORDPRESS " , it has  tons of functions for designing a theme , one not need to edit the core files of WORDPRESS  for designing a theme.  I am trying to create a similar web app (though not as huge as wordpress )  .

Comment: improved code highlight